# How to get a list of only TrueType fonts in FMX Delphi?

Tags: delphi, fonts, firemonkey

I have created a font selector dropdown box which is populated using the code given in the answer below.

[How to get the list of fonts available - Delphi XE3 + Firemonkey 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346620/how-to-get-the-list-of-fonts-available-delphi-xe3-firemonkey-2)

However, I'm converting the text to a path using TTextLayout.ConvertToPath(), and this only works with TrueType fonts. I'd therefore like to reduce the list to omit other font formats such as the one used by Courier. I can't see a way to do this using the above code. Only the name of the font is returned and not the format. Whichever method I use needs to work on Mac also. I'm using Delphi 10.4 FMX.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but for Windows, in EnumsFontsProc, you can examine the LogFont argument. According to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-logfonta) the member lfOutPrecision is OUT_STROKE_PRECIS for truetype font.

Comment: Thanks. That works to a certain extent. It removes several of the .fon fonts such as Courier and Terminal, but for some reason doesn't remove Script, Roman or Modern, which are also .fon format.

Comment: I also tried checking the OUT_STRING_PRECIS value, to reject any raster fonts, but this has the same effect leaving those 3 raster fonts.